# Combining two SQLDatabases with several tables; dropping duplicates in the process

Tags: mysql, merge, peewee

I am new to handling SQL databases, so I hope you don't mind the basic question.
For a research project I have to combine two SQL Databases with an identical structure.
They have been created from dumps of tweets and contain interreferenced tables for information on several predefined classes such as tweet text, tweet id, user (id), tweet id, contained hashtags etc.
They overlap to some extend, i.e. some tweets are contained in both databases.

They are built with Peewee, and are restricted to contain only unique observations.
I have tried to combine the two databases using the following syntax- to face the probably expectable error message 'unique constraint failed'.

How do I best go about this? I want to end up with one database containing a list of unique tweets.

```
#Merging the two databases
import sqlite3
tweets=sqlite3.connect("tweets_1.db")
tweets.execute("ATTACH 'tweets_2.db' as dba")

tweets_.execute("BEGIN")
for row in tweets_.execute("SELECT * FROM dba.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"):
combine = "INSERT INTO "+ row[1] + " SELECT * FROM dba." + row[1]
print(combine)
tweets_.execute(combine)
tweets_.commit()
tweets_.execute("detach database dba")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to run a number of queries:

1. Create a temporary table
2. Import both sets of data into it
3. Then run an INSERT INTO table SELECT DISTINCT(key_field) FROM temp table

I don't know if SQL lite supports temporary tables so it may have to be created and then dropped but that would be how I'd do it in mySQL